# How would I send push messages to android from my hardware which is esp8266 module? Without installing app in mobile, can I use internal services?

Tags: android, push-notification, esp8266, android-popupwindow

How would I send push messages to android from my hardware which is esp8266 module? **Without installing app in mobile**, can I use internal services?

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way to send a push notification to an Android phone without an app installed to receive it. However, there are pre-made apps that simply receive push notifications if your concern is developing an app, such as this: https://pushed.co/